# EntityCommandExecutionException Timeout Expired Only Sometimes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework 5 to connect to SQL Server 2008. I've imported a stored procedure into my project with no issues. The stored procedure has executed in the past with no issues at all up until I switched from using `.GroupBy().First()` in LINQ to get distinct results to getting unique results by using an `OUTER APPLY` in the stored procedure.

I switched to using an `OUTER APPLY` on SQL Server from the `.GroupBy()` in LINQ because, of course SQL is much faster.

Here is my SQL:

```
@USERID VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@ITEMTYPE VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@ITEMSUBTYPE VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@ITEMGROUP VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@ITEMNO VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL    

SELECT distinct orderformdump.itemno, 
case when @userid = '' then NULL else CAST((SELECT top 1 [UNITPRICE] FROM [ICPRICP] WHERE [ITEMNO] = ICITEM.ITEMNO AND [PRICELIST] in (select priclist from ARCUS where IDCUST in (select CUSTID from WEBLOGINACCESS where [USER] = @USERID)) and [CURRENCY] = 'CDN' and DPRICETYPE = 1) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) end as price,
isnull(deals.isindeal, CAST(0 AS BIT) ) isindeal
FROM ORDERFORMDUMP
INNER JOIN ICITEM ON ICITEM.FMTITEMNO = orderformdump.itemno
outer apply
(
 select top 1 CAST(1 AS BIT) as isindeal
 from PRD2 INNER JOIN PRH on PRD2.CODE = PRH.CODE 
 where ICITEM.ITEMNO = PRD2.ITEMNO and PRH.ACTIVE = 1  
 and cast(GETDATE() as DATE) between PRH.STARTDATE and isnull(PRH.ENDDATE, cast(GETDATE() as DATE))
) deals
where
(@ITEMNO IS NULL or ICITEM.FMTITEMNO = @ITEMNO)
and
(@ITEMSUBTYPE is null or ORDERFORMITEMSUBTYPEDUMP.ITEMSUBTYPE = @ITEMSUBTYPE)
and
(@ITEMTYPE is null or ORDERFORMITEMTYPEDUMP.ITEMTYPE = @ITEMTYPE)
and
(@ITEMGROUP is null or ORDERFORMITEMGROUPDUMP.ITEMGROUP = @ITEMGROUP)
```

Before, instead of the `OUTER APPLY` I had two `LEFT JOIN`s and the `isindeal` column was inside a `CASE` statement:

```
...
case when PRH.ACTIVE = 1 and PRH.STARTDATE < cast(GETDATE() as DATE) and (PRH.ENDDATE IS NULL OR PRH.ENDDATE >= cast(GETDATE() as DATE)) then CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END as isindeal
...
LEFT JOIN PRD2 on ICITEM.ITEMNO = PRD2.ITEMNO
LEFT JOIN PRH on PRD2.CODE = PRH.CODE
...
```

Here's the imported class in Entity Framework:

```
public partial class PRODUCTS_Result
{
    public string itemno { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
    public bool isindeal { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the stored procedure is called:

```
db.PRODUCTS(userid, itemtype, itemsubtype, itemgroup, itemno)
```

This is how it was being called before:

```
db.PRODUCTS(userid, itemtype, itemsubtype, itemgroup, itemno).GroupBy(i => i.itemno).Select(x => x.First());
```

Strangely enough, the timeout only happens when the stored procedure gets called with all null paramaters (ex. `db.PRODUCTS(null, null, null, null, null)`)

I tried setting the timeout to 5 minutes instead of the default 30 seconds, `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;`, but it just runs for the entire 5 minutes and still times out.

The stored procedure finishes execution in SQL Server in 3-5 seconds with all NULL values for the paramters, I've checked all the data types and they match up, so I've no idea why I get this timeout error only sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to this query

Long answer: Read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in TSQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)