# Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

In my application, queries are working fine.
For a single select query, i am getting below error.

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The
>   connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete
>   the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while
>   attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent
>   while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]
>   initialization=0; handshake=13914; [Login] initialization=0;
>   authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=1062;  --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

I have ran sqlprofiler for detecting deadlocks but found none.

I am running simple query through entity framework

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Strange, I'm getting the error from Azure SQL Server which should not be affected any lack of resource (RAM, CPU) what is advised in case of local machines (other host services).

Answer (score 6):

Here in stack overflow, there is a post called [Help troubleshooting SqlException: Timeout expired on connection, in a non-load situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421978/771579). It is  a problem very similar to your problem. Please take a look.

I will quote (from that post) a comment as a possible cause of your problem:

> "Not Enough Memory"
>
> "You may have 'Auto Close' enabled"
>
> "SQL Agent Jobs may be causing problems"

In that post you can see a very good explanation about the topic.

Comment: memory may be an issue because my application is running on Virtual machine but how to make sure this is the reason
auto close is disabled
SQL agent job are not running

Comment: Try to add more memory to your VMachine. Did you read the post? They mentioned how to check the memory performance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to .Close your connection before.

that's why: `Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.`

(I cant comment for now due to my reputation, dont take this as a full answer)

Comment: Connections are getting closed. I am disposing connection through using block

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the Active Directory. Maybe a port is blocked (for example 135), so a timeout occurred.